# Install MariaDB with custom my.ini file

Tags: innodb, mariadb, installation

I have an installation script for Windows to install mariaDB as service:

```
   mysql_install_db --datadir=c:/mariadb/data --service=MariaDB
```

It works, but I want to change the default my.ini file adding `innodb_file_per_table=0` setting before default table creation. 
How can I change the my.ini before default db creation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no urgency of getting that setting made.  After the install is finished,

1. Locate `my.cnf`
2. `my.cnf` may have some "includes" at the end.  One of those places is the 'proper' place to do the next step.
3. Add any extra settings at the end of the `[mysqld]` section of the file.
4. Restart `mysqld` by restarting the MariaDB 'service'.

You can also set that without restarting, but the setting would be lost at the next restart:

1. Connect to MariaDB as 'root'.  (I like to use the `mysql` commandline tool, but there are other ways.)
2. `SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=0;`

Now any `CREATE TABLE` will put the data and indexes in `ibdata1`.

Note:  To move a table in `ibdata1` from or to its own `.ibd` file (tablespace), do the `SET` and do `ALTER TABLE name ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: I think there is urgency because standard table (mysql.users etc.) are created during setup. Therefore if I don't want IBD files for these table I have to set it before mysql db creation.

Comment: A second problem is that I tried to ALTER TABLE after that settings but the IBD file is still mandatory for the table, I tried with MariaDB 10.1.18. I stopped the service, changed my.ini with innodb_file_per_table=0, restarted service, altered one table, stopped service, removed IBD table file, restarted and the table wasn't accessibile. I also tried to create a new table and IBD file is not created, so I'm sure the settings is on, but seems the ALTER doesn't move tablespace to log files, the only way is to re-create the table (for example with a dump).

Comment: @Tobia - `mysql`.`users` is `ENGINE=MyISAM` (pre-8.0), so no `.ibd`.  Which version are you running?

Comment: You are right Rick, there is not problem for standard mysql tables. I will set the var just after installation thanks.